# Ввод/вывод данных с клавиатуры с помощью case

Tags: java, наследование, switch, case

Дорогие программисты. По задумке моей программы пользователь вводит несколько строк, а потом программа их выводит на экран. Загвоздка в том, что я делаю это через 2 кейса. И поскольку значение переменных в каждом кейсе не сохраняется, то я сами переменные закинул в паблик класс, однако при запуске выдает ошибку.

Основной класс:

```
 case 1: //кейс с вводом содержимого n строк
                System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");

                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    data.n = scanner.nextInt();
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");
                    return;
                }


                scanner.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {

                  System.out.printf((i + 1) + " ");
                  data.strings[i] = scanner.nextLine(); //ругается на ошибку


                }



         case 2:  //кейс с выводом содержимого n строк

                for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {

                    System.out.println(data.strings[i]);

                }
            break;
```

Класс с переменными:

```
public class Data {
int n;
String[] strings = new String[n];
}
```

Код ошибки: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: какой смысл этих case?

Comment: А ошибка - это выход за рамки массива

Comment: В каком месте идет инициализация массива? Вы передали туда n, но это n надо указать еще

Comment: Смысл при нажатии единицы в программе идет считывание данных с клавиатуры, а при двойке - их вывод. Да, получается, что ошибка состоит в этом, получается если обходится без кейсов и инициализировать в основной класс мои строки и кол-во заданное пользователем, то все хорошо работает. А через наследование другого класса появляется ошибка. Не пойму как исправить ее

Comment: Я ввожу также с клавиатуры значение n, в начале первого класса идет его скан.

Comment: нельзя ли кейсы заменить на if? Тогда отпадают все проблемы с инициализацией

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Где у вас создается `data`? Очевидно, что где-то перед вашими кейсами есть строка `Data data = new Data();` И тут то и создается объект, в котором инициализируется массив `String[] strings = new String[n];`. Но поскольку `n` имеет дефолтное значение (0), то и массив создается нулевой длины. Соответственно, доступ к его элементам получить нельзя, т.к. их там нет. Вам нужно в классе `Data` написать конструктор, в который передавать `n` и тут же инициализировать массив стрингов.

Основной класс:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    Data data = null;

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Input 1 or 2:");
        int option = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();

        switch (option) {
            case 1: // кейс с вводом содержимого n строк
                System.out.print("Введите количество строк: ");

                if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
                    data = new Data(scanner.nextInt());
                } else {
                    System.out.print("Введены некорректные данные!");
                    return;
                }
                scanner.nextLine();

                for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
                    System.out.print((i + 1) + " ");
                    data.strings[i] = scanner.nextLine(); // НЕ ругается на ошибку
                }

                break;

            case 2:  //кейс с выводом содержимого n строк
                if (data != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < data.n; i++) {
                        System.out.println(data.strings[i]);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `Data`

```
public class Data {
int n;
String[] strings;

public Data(int n) {
    this.n = n;
    strings = new String[n];
}
```

}

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, однако немного не понял, что нужно делать в конструкторе, сканировать n?

Comment: Смотрите, перед кейсами у вас создается `data` и в ней `n == 0`, а массив стрингов создается нулевой длины. Когда вы попадаете в `case 1`, то менять `n` уже поздно, т.к. массив был создан ранее, когда `n` было = 0. Вам нужно объявить `Data data = null` перед кейсами, потом, если входите в `case 1`, создаете `data = new Data(n);`. В классе `Data` пишете конструктор `Data(int n) { String[] strings = new String[n]; }`. Нужно также иметь в виду, что не выполнив `case 1` у вас будет `data == null` - надо делать проверку и не пускать во второй кейс.

Comment: Все сделал, как вы сказали, однако когда я вводил `data = new Data(n)`; в `case 1`, то переменную n в этой строке программа не видит.

Comment: Посмотрел ваш ответ. проверил - все работает, спасибо большое вам!